# Этимология "предвосхитить"

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

[https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/предвосхитить](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C):

> **Этимология**
>
> Происходит от ??

От чего?

Доп. вопрос: глаголы "предвосхитить" и "восхитить" семантически не связаны?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  ВосхИщенной и восхищённой,
  Сны видящей средь бела дня,
  Все спящей видели меня,
  Никто меня не видел сонной.
              М. И. Цветаева
```

**ОТВЕТ**

***Хитить*** (по Фасмеру) — ***восхитить*** (по значению приставки ВОЗ) — ***предвосхИтить*** (толковый словарь Кузнецова).

**Исторически** однокоренные слова, корень ***- ХИТ***.

Приставка ***ВОЗ/ВОС*** —  многозначная.  ***Похитить*** и ***восхитить*** — близкие по значению слова, но приставка ВОЗ вносит новый **оттенок** значения: интенсивное или резкое, внезапное начало действия, состояния.

**Восхищение** (по Далю) — это другое значения ***ВОЗ/ВОС***: доведение до предела,необычность,торжественность; увлечь в высоту.

Приставка ***ПРЕД*** — сделать, применить, употребить раньше других, опередить кого-, что-л., предугадать.

**Например:**

**«Иоганн Гете (1749–1832)** был не только поэтом, мыслителем, но и естествоиспытателем, разносторонним ученым, выполнившим ряд работ по сравнительной морфологии растений и животных, по физике (оптика и акустика), минералогии, геологии и метеорологии. Его гениальные догадки в работах по естествознанию **предвосхитили** дальнейшую теорию развития.

**МАТЕРИАЛЫ ПО ТЕМЕ**

**[Большой толковый словарь](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=49&dicts%5B%5D=42)**

**ПРЕДВОСХИТИТЬ,** -хищу, -хитишь; предвосхищённый; -щён, -щена, -щено; св. что. Книжн. Сделать, применить, употребить раньше других, опередить кого-, что-л., предугадать. П. открытие. П. чью-л. мысль. П. будущее. Предвосхищать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Не предвосхищай событий! Предвосхищаться, -ается; страд. Предвосхищение, -я; ср. П. событий.

**[Приставка ВОЗ](https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts%5B%5D=42)**

**ВОЗ.**.. (перед звонкими согласными: воздать, возблагодарить); ВОЗО... (перед некоторыми группами согласных: возомнить, возобладать); ВОС... (перед глухими согласными: воссоздать, восславить). Приставка (служит для образования глаг. и сущ.). 1. **Обозначает направленность** движения, действия **вверх**. Возвышать - возвысить (голос), возводить - возвести (глаза к небу), возносить - вознести (молитву), воздевать - воздеть (руки), воздвигнуть - воздвигать (башню). 2. Обозначает **интенсивное или резкое, внезапное начало действия, состояния**. Возликовать (от успеха), возмечтать (о славе), воспылать (любовью), возгордиться, вознегодовать. 3. Обозначает совершение действия **вновь, заново.** Возобновлять - возобновить (дружбу), воссоздавать - воссоздать (картину), воскрешать - воскресить (событие в памяти), восстанавливать - восстановить (завод), возрождение традиций. 4. Обозначает совершение действия **в ответ** на что-л., в соответствии с чем-л. Возмещать - возместить (убытки), возвращать - возвратить (долг), воздавать - воздать (должное), возражать - возразить (на критику), вознаграждение (за услуги). 5. Обозначает **завершённость действия, состояния; доведение до какого-л. предела.** Воспитать (новое поколение), воспрепятствовать (кому-, чему-л.), воспротивиться (насилию), воспользоваться (удобным моментом), востребовать (багаж), возмужать. 6. **Высок. Обозначает торжественность, необычность совершения действия, состояния.** Воссесть (на престол), восседать (на троне), возвести (в сан), воскурить (фимиам), возлечь (куда-л.), возлежать (где-л.), воспеть (подвиг), воззвание (к народу).

**ВОСХИЩЕНИЕ,** -я; ср. **Высшая степень** удовлетворения, удовольствия от чего-л.; восторг. Привести, прийти в в. Выразить своё в. кому-л.

**[Словарь Фасмера](https://lexicography.online/etymology/%D1%85/-%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)**

**-ХИТИТЬ:** похи́тить, восхити́ть, хи́щный (ввиду наличия -щ- заимств. из цслав.), укр. хита́ти «шатать», хитки́й «шаткий», похита́ти «покачать»; др.-русск. хытати, хычу «хватать, похищать», ст.-слав. хытити, хыштѫ «схватить», въсхытити «вырвать, увлечь», болг. хи́там «спешу», сербохорв. хи̏тати «хватать, бросать, спешить», хи̏тити «хватать, спешить», словен. hítati «похищать, бросать», hȋt «бросок», чеш. chytiti, сhуtаti «хватать, ловить», слвц. сhуtit᾽, сhуtаt᾽ — то же, в.-луж. chyćić «хватать», н.-луж. chyśiś, сhуtаś «бросать». || Связано чередованием гласных с хвата́ть, хвати́ть (см.); ср. Бернекер I, 414. Недостоверна связь с гот. afskiuban «отталкивать», нов.-в.-н. schieben «толкать, двигать» (Младенов 667).

**[Словарь Даля](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/enc2p/217258)**

**ВОСХИЩАТЬ**, восхитить кого, похищать, выхватывать, уносить, уводить силою; увлекать в высоту;
| возносить кого духом, приводить в восторженное состояние, в восторг, восхищение; радовать, утешать в высшей степени. Восхищать у кого силу. ·стар. одолевать, побеждать кого. -ся, ·возвр. и страд. смотря по смыслу речи, во всеех ·знач. Восхищенный, похищенный;
| о человеке, восторженный, отрешившийся и вознесшийся духом; кидающийся в крайности, восторженный и самоуверенный, эксцентрический человек. Восхищение ср. действие и ·сост. по гл. на -ть и на -ся. Более употр. ·в·знач. восторга, неистовой радости. Восхитительный, приводящий в восхищение, в восторг. Восхитительность жен. свойство всего того, что восхищает. Восхищенность жен. свойство восхищенного, эксцентричность. Восхититель муж. -ница жен. похититель, хищник; тать, вор;

**[Кем был загадочный «восхищеник» во времена Руси? История слова «восхищение»](https://%D0%9A%D0%B5%D0%BC%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9%20%C2%AB%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%C2%BB%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0%20%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D0%B8?%20%D0%98%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%20%C2%AB%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%C2%BB)**

Comment: Следуя материалам, семантика "предвосхитить" -- "раньше других увлекать в высоту, приводить в восторженное состояние". Однако Большой толковый словарь не указывает на "увлекать в высоту, приводить в восторженное состояние". Почему приставка "пред" отменяет семантику "увлекать в высоту, приводить в восторженное состояние"?

Comment: Я добавила материал по приставке ВОЗ/ВОС.

Comment: Вопрос не по приставке ВОЗ/ВОС. Вопрос по приставке ПРЕД. Обычно приставка ПРЕД добавляет семантику "заранее" (сделать, применить, употребить раньше других), не меняя семантики слова, к которому она добавляется. Пример: предугадать -- заранее угадать. Здесь добавление ПРЕД к "угадать" _не меняет_ семантику глагола "угадать". Вопрос: почему в "предвосхитить" приставка ПРЕД _меняет_ семантику глагола "восхитить" (увлекать в высоту, приводить в восторженное состояние) на семантику "сделать, применить, употребить".

Comment: Я же изменила ответ, добавила словарь с различными  значениями приставки ВОЗ:  Вариант 1:  хИтить  — восхИтить  —  предвосхИтить,  ВОС (1)  со значением интенсивное или резкое, внезапное начало действия, состояния.
Вариант 2.  хИтить  — восхитИть,  ВОС (2)  со значением увлечь в высоту, необычность, торжественность действия.

Comment: По Тихонову у "предвосхитить" корень не "хит" (как вы пишите), а "[предвосхит](https://gufo.me/dict/tikhonov/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C)". По Тихонову у "восхитить" корень не "хит" (как вы пишите), а "[восхит](https://gufo.me/dict/tikhonov/%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C(%D1%81%D1%8F))". Разные корни -- разные семантики. Для сравнения: по Тихонову у "предугадать" и "угадать" корень одинаковый -- "гад". В "предугадать" семантика "угадать" сохраняется. В "предвосхитить" семантика "восхитить" не сохраняется. Понимаю так.

Comment: Остается только ответить: почему не сохраняется? С чего и начали, только  Х обозначили через У.  Я понимаю так: семантика не сохраняется, потому что ее там и не было. ВосхитИть - это не восхИтить (такого слова нет в языке). Есть близкое по смыслу слово – похИтить как вариант "восхИтить" с тем же ударением и тем же оттенком смысла.  Кстати,  в слове похитить выделяют корень ХИТ https://morphemeonline.ru/П/похитить  https://kartaslov.ru/разбор-слова-по-составу/похитить

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. У меня есть проблема с ударением в "предвосхитить". Интуитивно делаю ударение на последнюю И, хотя нужно на предпоследнюю И. Это навело на (ложное) родство "предвосхитить" и "восхитить". Доп. вопрос: почему в "предвосхищая" ударение на А, а не на И?

Comment: Спасибо за приемку ответа и очень интересный вопрос. Проблема с ударением в этом слове у многих, вот  статья на тему https://rg.ru/2008/11/20/koroleva.html  // В словаре Резниченко говорится: ударение в деепричастии обычно делается на ту же гласную, что в форме 1-го  лица ед. числа глагола. ПредвосхищАть — предвосхищУ — предвосхищАя https://gramota.ru/poisk?query=предвосхищать&mode=slovari&l=1&dicts[]=49  Таким образом, ударение меняется уже в форме глагола несов.вида.  Это скорее фонетика, такое слово неудобно произносить иначе.