# Глагол "похитить": почему выделяют приставку ПО?

Tags: морфемный-разбор

1. Слова ***"хитить"*** нет в языке, но есть слова ***хищение, похищение, хищник***, так что значение корня понятно.

***Похитить*** — непроизводное слово? Но тогда надо выделять корень ***ПОХИТ***. Но у [Тихонова](https://gufo.me/dict/tikhonov) и у [Потиха](https://www.booksite.ru/fulltext/1475592/text.pdf) указывается корень ***ХИТ:*** по/хит/и/ть.

И какое значение имеет здесь приставка ***ПО***?

2. Кстати, у Тихонова у глаголов ***восхит/И/ть*** и ***предвосхИт/и/ть*** приставки входят в состав корня.

Почему же такие **разные решения**? Ведь в современном языке значения всех морфем понятно. Может, здесь разные оттенки значений?

Помогите, пожалуйста, **разобраться.**  Для чего надо?
Вопрос по приставкам обсуждался в недавней **[теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478524/%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C/478532?noredirect=1#comment520016_478532)** об этимологии глагола ***"предвосхитить".***

Answer (score 0):

Итак, корень ***ХИТ*** выделяется в **непроизводном** слове? А почему?

Можно предположить, что такой выбор соответствует тому **значению,** которое носители современного языка видят в этом корне. К примеру, есть существительное **"хищение"** с тем же значением корня.

Таким образом, это **формально-структурный** подход к морфемному анализу, когда выделяются **узнаваемые** в современном языке морфемы, без соответствия реальной **словообразовательной** схеме. Такой подход к выделению более **удобен** в данном случае.

Мы понимаем смысл корня ***ХИТ*** и  приставки ***ПО***, которая используется при образовании глаголов **совершенного** вида.

О разных подходах к анализу говорится в ответе **[по этой теме](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/478589/%D0%95%D1%89%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7-%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%83/478605#478605https://).**

**Из словаря:**

**ПОХИТИТЬ,** -хищу, -хитишь; похищенный; -щен, -а, -о; св. кого-что. Тайно унести, увести или увезти; выкрасть. П. ценные бумаги. П. коня. Время похитило многое (лишило многого). Разрешите п. вашего гостя (шутл.). Похищать, -аю, -аешь; нсв. Похищаться, -ается; страд. Похищение, -я; ср. П. невесты. Возбудить дело о похищении ценностей.

**ХИЩЕНИЕ; ХИЩЕНЬЕ,** -я; ср. 1. Преступное присвоение чужого имущества; воровство. Мелкие хищения. Х. в особо крупных размерах. Х. государственного имущества на местах. Возбудить дело по факту хищения. Х. века! (о крупном ограблении, краже). 2. То, что похищено, украдено. Установить истинную стоимость